# Why was the SpaceX Demo 2 spashdown livestream so devoid of visuals?

Tags: spacex, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, dragon, commercial-crew-program

Today's successful splashdown was tremendously boring compared to what we are used to from SpaceX launches. The mission statistics, the timeline, inner cockpit, etc was not shown during the telecast. Just a camera was still capturing the room with few people working on the computers? Why did they avoid displaying everything from the returning mission? The only action was a narrator just briefing at regular intervals. All this was hyped but ended up in a boring video compared to what we are used to from SpaceX launches. Any explanation?

Comment: Please don't get combative or insulting; there are likely some real reasons why there is less detailed coverage on the landing than on the launch. I have some guesses to why, but they mostly relate to 1. communications blackout during reentry, 2. limited communications equipment on the capsule as opposed to the trunk, 3. NASA hesitance to show live video inside the capsule where there is a good chance that a failure would allow viewers to see the astronauts' final moments. In general, Earth gets much less info on landing than on launch.

Comment: I edited your question into something that is more likely to receive answers.

Comment: @CourageousPotato That makes sense, but why would #3 be more likely than during launch? Nobody has ever died in reentry in a capsule except by depressurization without space suits.

Comment: @ikrase Launch failures generally result in more explosions, which are more effective at cutting out a video feed than, for example, a parachute failure or water flooding into the capsule.